# Using of __block variable inside a block

Tags: objective-c++

I have a class like this

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(const int *a, int *aC= nullptr);
    MyClass(MyClass &myClass) = delete;

    MyClass(MyClass &&yClass) noexcept;
}
```

I have my processor function defined like this

```
my_processor = ^(int* c1, const int* a1){
  __block MyClass obj(a1 c1);

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
  {                
     ProcessMyData(obj);
  });

}
```

When i run the code, i get a crash like this

```
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff20359029 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell + 41
1   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00007fff2004f3d1 _Block_copy + 117
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is this C++ or objective-c question? Please choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we'll be able to conclusively find the source of your problem given the code you've provided, as it's insufficient to reproduce the issue.

The most obvious possibility that stands out to me is:

```
my_processor = ^(int* c1, const int* a1){
  __block MyClass obj(a1 c1);

 dispatch_async(
```

Here, `c1` and `a1` are pointers. I assume that unlike in the code you posted, these parameters to the constructor influence the constructed object's state in some way. Does their lifetime matter for the internal state of the object? In other words, is either of the pointers stored in the object, and will it be dereferenced later? The block passed to `dispatch_async()` is likely called on a different thread, at an indeterminate point in time.

So if either of the pointers is stored in `MyClass`, they **must** remain valid until the async dispatch is guaranteed to have completed. (Consider copying the data instead of storing the pointer if this is hard to guarantee.)

It would probably also help to know the exact timing of the crash. You could also explicitly `_Block_copy` for diagnostic purposes instead of letting it happen on demand to see if that provokes a crash too.

But essentially, you haven't provided enough context here to give anything close to a definitive answer. Edit your question so that the code is runnable and exhibits the crash and we can help you.